# using cloudinary api in conjunction with Epress and EJS

Tags: node.js, ejs, cloudinary

I am trying to use cloudinary's node api to make an unsigned upload directly from an EJS template bypassing uploading the picture to the server first.

I have included all the required scripts according to the documentation like so...

```
        <script
            src="/node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js"
            lang="text/javascript"
        ></script>
        <script 
            src="/node_modules/blueimp-file-upload/js/vendor/jquery.ui.widget.js"
            type="text/javascript"
        ></script>
        <script
            src="/node_modules/blueimp-file-upload/js/jquery.iframe-transport.js"
            type="text/javascript"
        ></script>
        <script
            src="/node_modules/blueimp-file-upload/js/jquery.fileupload.js"
            type="text/javascript"
        ></script>
        <script
            src="/node_modules/cloudinary-jquery-file-upload/cloudinary-jquery-file-upload.js"
            type="text/javascript"
        ></script>
```

yet when I try to make a call to a cloudinary method...`<%-cloudinary.uploader.unsigned_image_upload_tag('image_id', preset_name,{ callback: cloudinary_cors })%>`

> > 44|         <%cloudinary.uploader.unsigned_image_upload_tag('image_id',
> > 45|                     preset_name,{ callback: cloudinary_cors })%>
> > 46|
> > 47|

cloudinary is not defined

anyone run into this before who can give me a hand?

Answer (score 0):

You are missing the cloudinary initialization step:
`$.cloudinary.config({ cloud_name: 'sample', secure: true});`
You can follow the documentation for more detail: https://cloudinary.com/documentation/jquery_integration#installation